# How to pass hex value in uri?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest, hex, freebase

Not sure if this can be done or if there is a good workaround.  But I have guids (hex values) to objects in Freebase, and I need to pass those values using GET to fetch the object from Freebase and mash it with some data I have stored in my app.

So the url looks like http://foo.com/object-category/#9202a8c04000641f80000000000495ec

But I can't see to get that value out of the uri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment is never sent to the server. It needs to be processed on the client side, in JavaScript.